# The program hangs when I try to replace image?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("edit"))
    {
         string status = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["status"].Value.ToString();

         if (status == "1") 
         {        
              dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["edit"].Value = Properties.Resources.edit_disable;
         }
    }
}
```

When I try to replace image here:

```
 dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["edit"].Value = Properties.Resources.edit_disable;
```

Program hangs and image and is rendered infinity

Comment: have you tried removing and re-adding this resource?

Comment: Yes, it is DataGridViewImageColumn

Comment: Step thru the code to see if an infinite loop is occurring.  The `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` event changes `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["edit"]`, which fires `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` again, which changes `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["edit"]`, ad infinitum.

Comment: I change image only by condition. not always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected the wrong event for changing an Image. The event `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` is fired when an image changes, so if you use this event to change an image, you are getting into an infinite loop.

Since your code is querying the cell's `Value`, you might want to switch to a different event, which is fired when the row / cell data changes or binds, such as `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` or  `dataGridView1.RowsAdded`:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
     string status = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["status"].Value.ToString();

     if (status == "1") 
     {        
         dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["edit"].Value = Properties.Resources.edit_disable;
     }
}
```

Comment: What to use instead? when i need to check each row value and format column cell?

Comment: can you share a little example, i dont understand clearly

Comment: It's the exact code you written, only put it on a different event method.

Comment: Yes, I tried just replace method, but I can not acess this `dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]`

Comment: There is not property: `e.ColumnIndex`

Comment: @OPV You don't need it. See updated answer. You are referring to the cell by name anyway.

Comment: @OPV It should. Are you sure? You do have an `if` condition... Please double check

Comment: Yes, I did: `Console.WriteLine(status);` it shows only two rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151914/discussion-between-opv-and-koby-douek).